# Jmeter while controller 2nd condition not working

Tags: jmeter

I have a thread group with a **While controller**.
At there I have set below condition.

```
${__javaScript(((${__time()} - ${LOOPSTART}) < 600000)  || ("${Queuing_Status}" == "QUEUED")) }
```

`${Queuing_Status}` is a user defined variable with the text `QUEUED`.

`${LOOPSTART}` is coming from a `Bean shell sampler`, and below is the code for that.

```
vars.put("LOOPSTART", System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
```

I have noticed that it will never reach the 2nd condition.
So what might be the possible error with my condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `&&` operator instead of `||` one:

```
${__javaScript(((${__time()} - ${LOOPSTART}) < 60000)  && ("${Queuing_Status}" == "QUEUED")) }
```

More information: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter)

Also:

- [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function is recommended for using instead of __javaScript(). Alternatively you can consider [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as well. The reason is the same: performance, moreover [JavaScript has been removed in JDK15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) so you might face problems with JavaScript in Java 15+